# how to write output into txt file?

Tags: perl

I want to merge two files and print into one txt file.

I already successful merge two data but unable to print it into txt file. by now, the output just printed in xterm.

input 1:

```
a123
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

input 2:

```
a123
x
y
x
c
v
```

current output was displayed in xterm not in txt file.

```
a123
b
c
d 
e
f
g
x
y
x
c
v
```

run my script:

```
perl test1.pl file1 file2
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
my $files = $#ARGV; # get number of files - 1
while (my $file = shift @ARGV) {
   open my $fh, "<", $file;
   <$fh> unless $files == @ARGV;  #discard header unless first file
   printf while <$fh>;
}
```

save inside one txt file

Comment: Call it like `perl test1.pl file1 file2 > textfile.txt`. This is to provoke clarification whether it should just end up in a textfile or should be programmed into the script. Please also state whether you want selectable output file name, e.g. by a third parameter.

Comment: yes.. it solved my issue.. thanks

Comment: Should also be `print`, not `printf`. Don't use `printf` without a formatting pattern!

Comment: when i tried this script with the real data(large data), why there are some line of data missing? about more than half

Comment: the missing line started with ^@ --> asr/rt_main/,^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@

Comment: @sitinadhirahZainurin: why "basic" in the tags? No Basic related question!

Comment: Also, for a better code- please 'close' the file-handle after doing all the work. https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html

Answer (score 1):

Redirct the output of script in .txt file.

```
perl test1.pl file1 file2 > output.txt
```

Comment: Hmmm, that seems familiar. If I only knew where I have read that before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the text file programmatically in the script then you can use following script.

This script takes the text file name also as a command line argument, last command line argument would used as the file name in which the content will be written.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $outfile = $ARGV[$#ARGV];
my @files = @ARGV[0..$#ARGV-1];

open my $outf, ">", $outfile or
    die "Unable to open the file: $!";

my $i = 0;
foreach my $file (@files) {
    open my $f, "<", $file;
    while (<$f>) {
        next if ($.== 1 && $i>0);
        print $outf $_;
    }
    close $f;
    $i++;
}

close $outf;
```

Command to execute the script :

```
perl test1.pl file1 file2 file3.txt
```